# Change website link colors on button click

Tags: javascript, button

I created a linear-gradient and animated it in javascript and set it as the background to my website. Then I added a button in HTML that when clicked the colors of the gradient switch out.

Now I am trying to make the button also change the color of the text links on my page, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone please let me know where I went wrong? Thanks.

Java script

```
var angle = 0, color = "#666", colors = "#000", font = "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)";
var changeBackground = function() {
  angle = angle + .4
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle + 
"deg, " + colors + ", " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ",  " 
+ colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors 
+ ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ", " + color;
  requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground)
}

var changeFont = function() {
  document.a.style.color = "color(" + font;
}

changeBackground()

document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  color = (color != "#666") ? "#666" : "#fff";
  colors = (colors != "#000") ? "#000" : "#6839ba";
  font = (font != "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)") ? "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)" 
: "rgba(247, 201, 180, .3)";
})
```

Html button and links

```
<main class="main">
    <button class="Btn" id="myBtn">Click</button>
    <ul class="position">
        <li class="fnup"><a href="#">fn-up   </a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">about   </a></li>
        <li class="issue hover"><a href="#">issue 0 </a></li>
        <li class="contact hover"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `changeFont` when the button is clicked. You also need for `changeFont` to iterate over all `a`s and set their `style.color` property.

While you *can* do this, it's pretty unreadable IMO because the colors are too similar:

```js
var angle = 0, color = "#666", colors = "#000", font = "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)";
var changeBackground = function() {
  angle = angle + .4
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(" + angle + 
"deg, " + colors + ", " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ",  " 
+ colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ",  " + color + ", " + colors 
+ ",  " + color + ", " + colors + ", " + color;
  requestAnimationFrame(changeBackground)
}

var changeFont = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.style.color = font);
}

changeBackground();
changeFont();

document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  color = (color != "#666") ? "#666" : "#fff";
  colors = (colors != "#000") ? "#000" : "#6839ba";
  font = (font != "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)") ? "rgba(102, 102, 102, .3)" 
: "rgba(247, 201, 180, .3)";
  changeFont();
})
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <button class="Btn" id="myBtn">Click</button>
  <ul class="position">
    <li class="fnup"><a href="#">fn-up   </a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="#">about   </a></li>
    <li class="issue hover"><a href="#">issue 0 </a></li>
    <li class="contact hover"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks its perfect! There are other elements effecting the links that make it more legible, but I wanted to keep the example simplified here :)

Comment: Hello, still there? Just curious if you could help me out with this. Trying to add more elements to this function and am struggling with syntax. Can I target a modal class like this document.querySelector('.modal').style.backgroundColor = "blue";?

Comment: I've made a new post but no one has been able to help. If you wanted to check it out